# Camera not in /dev/ how to create one

Tags: pi-3, usb, camera, input-device

Does someone know if it's possible to create a new "/dev/video0" with some informations (e.g idVendor, idProduct, ...). Our problem is that when we plug in our camera, it doesn't create a "/dev/*" device, but we're able to find its address "0xXXXXXX" by using a little java program. If someone has any instructions, that would be pretty cool ! 
Thanks :) (Our camera is a Celestron NexImage 5)

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is `mknod`

However, the creation of special device files is not for the faint of heart.  Make sure you know exactly what you are doing.

For further reading:

[mknod manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mknod.1.html)

[Writing a simple device driver](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/195-simple-driver-for-linux-os)

Comment: Do you know if mknod is available on Raspbian ? Because we cannot use this command actually. It's not recognized :/

Comment: Ups my bad, we got it, we will look on this way ! Thanks :)